# Does an external force on airplane door midair change the direction of the plane very slighty?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

When the airplane is midair, and there is higher pressure inside the plane than outside. An external force is pushing the airplane door from outside inwards (typical airplane door that open inwards), but the external applied force is not enough to overcome the air pressure of the plane. In this situation, is the net force on the side of the door of the plane very slightly less than the force on the other side of the plane? And does this cause a very slight movement of the aircraft to the side opposite of the door?

Comment: When you pull or push with your hands, don't forget what your feet are doing. Like trying to push your car while inside it.

Comment: You are right. But what if we would change the situation to an external force pushing the airplane door from outside to inside the plane? And the applied force is only on the door?

Comment: Well, yeah if you push a balloon on the outside, it deforms a bit and also moves a bit. Pneumatics.

Comment: Isn't an airplane door working like a bath plug? Isn't pushing against the balloon not a bit different than pushing against the airplane door?

Comment: Same thing as far as I'm concerned. You're either transferring force through the skin directly or through compression of the air within.

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks for explaining.